# What do we need the BiFunction interface for?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

The definition of the `BiFunction` interface contains a method `apply(T t, U u)`, which accepts two arguments. However, I don't understand the use or purpose of this interface and method. What do we need this interface for?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem with this question is that it's not clear whether you see the purpose of a `Function`, which has a method `apply(T t)`.

The value of all the functional types is that you can pass code around like data. One common use of this is the *callback*, and until Java 8, we used to have to do this with anonymous class declarations:

```
ui.onClick(new ClickHandler() {
    public void handleAction(Action action) {
        // do something in response to a click, using `action`.
    }
}
```

Now with lambdas we can do that much more tersely:

```
ui.onClick( action -> { /* do something with action */ });
```

We can also assign them to variables:

```
Consumer clickHandler = action -> { /* do something with action */ };
ui.onClick(clickHandler);
```

... and do the usual things we do with objects, like put them in collections:

```
Map<String,Consumer> handlers = new HashMap<>();
handlers.put("click", handleAction);
```

A `BiFunction` is just this with two input parameters. Let's use what we've seen so far to do something useful with `BiFunctions`:

```
Map<String,BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer>> operators = new HashMap<>();
operators.put("+", (a,b) -> a + b);
operators.put("-", (a,b) -> a - b);
operators.put("*", (a,b) -> a * b);

...

// get a, b, op from ui
ui.output(operators.get(operator).apply(a,b));
```

Comment: Thanks @peter for your help

Comment: `BiFunction` requires three generic types, one for each argument and the last for the `return` type.  +1 for a good explanation of the `super` though :)

Answer (score 3):

One of usages of `BiFunction` is in the `Map.merge` method.

Here is an example usage of the `Map.merge` method, which uses a `BiFunction` as a parameter. What `merge` does is basically replaces the value of the given key with the given value if the value is null or the key does not have a value. Otherwise, replace the value of the given key after applying the `BiFunction`.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("1", null);
map.put("2", "Hello");
map.merge("1", "Hi", String::concat);
map.merge("2", "Hi", String::concat);
System.out.println(map.get("1")); // Hi
System.out.println(map.get("2")); // HelloHi
```

If a `BiFunction` were not used, you would have to write a lot more code, even spanning several lines.

Here is a link that shows all the usages of `BiFunction` in the JDK: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/class-use/BiFunction.html

Go check it out!

Answer (score 0):

An extra example of BiFunction is `reduce()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5,5,10));

        Integer reduce = list.stream().reduce(0, (v1,v2) -> v1+v2);
        System.out.println(reduce); // result is: 20

}
```